# Disable automatically inserted space after dot

Tags: react-native

I have an URL form field of type  where a space is inserted automatically after period/dot is pressed.

How do i disable this effect? I'm currently using something like:
`onTextChange((val) => val.trim())`

But it looks kinda dumb when the cursor removes the space automatically

Comment: val.trim().toString()